# Rails Table - Dynamic Conditional Font Formatting

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to set the font color of dynamic values as follows:  if `incident.state_id = 1`, then red font, if `incident.state_id = 2`, then yellow font, if `incident.state_id = 3`, then red font.

```
incident.state_id = 1 : state.name = "Pending Investigation"
incident.state_id = 2 : state.name = "Investigation in Progress"
incident.state_id = 3 : state.name = "Investigation Closed"
```

I have adopted the following chunk of coffeescript, but I know zilch about js/coffee, so I don't know what to change to make this work.

Currently, all state fields show as red.

**incidents.js.coffee:**

```
$(".state").each ->
  $this = $(this)
  value = $this.text()
  if value = 1
    $this.addClass "red"
  else if value = 2
    $this.addClass "yellow"
  else
    $this.addClass "green"
```

**application.html.erb**

```
td.state {
}

.red {
    color: #f99;
}
.yellow {
    color: #ff9;
}
.green {
    color: #9f9;
}
```

**incidents.html.erb:**

```
<td class="state"><%= incident.state.name %></td>
```

Comment: Are all of the incidents rendered in one shot on the server?  Can a user change the incident state from the page?

Comment: `if value = 1` doesn't do what you think it does, `if value == 1` OTOH...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with coffee script (for this)?

Instead, I suggest setting the correct class in the erb file, like so:

```
<% if incident.state_id == 1  %>
    <td class="red"><%= incident.state.name %></td>
<% elsif incident.state_id == 2 %>
    <td class="yellow"><%= incident.state.name %></td>
<% else %>
    <td class="green"><%= incident.state.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

This is probably not the cleanest way to do this, but should solve the immediate problem.

Comment: Seriously?  That easy?!  Thank you - I was overthinking it.

Comment: This won't address the case where the incidents are dynamically added to the page after it has loaded.  And, the if switches are not as DRY as the css classes below.

Comment: @steakchaser I agree. I like your answer better, all around. I've been away from rails for too long, so I gave the answer I was sure would work, rather than your ERB, which I did not remember for certain.

Answer (score 2):

If you're incidents are all rendered from the server and are not dynamically added to the page, then you don't really need any JS to set the class.  Just simply create some css classes that use the state id:

```
td {
  .state-1 {
    color: #f99;
  }
  .state-2 {
    color: #ff9;
  }
  .state-3 {
    color: #9f9;
  }
}
```

Your view would then look like this:

```
<td class="<%= state-#{incident.state_id} %>"><%= incident.state.name %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks steakchaser.  The values are dynamically pulled, but thanks for your response!